# What is best strategy to upload multiple documents for single entity with metadata auto-set for all files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, metadata

We are planning to use SharePoint 2016 as DMS for our organization. I could not find satisfactory answer to my query: how can I upload multiple supporting documents for single entity, at the same time setting required metadata automatically for all those documents.  For example, HR wants to upload all documents related to an employee; the list could include educational certificates, medical certificates, legal documents etc. HR user wants to upload the bunch of file togather in one go, setting the required metadata of EmployeeCode, EmployeeName and Department automatically for all those documents.

Please guide me best strategy to achieve the same, and how much manual coding would that require.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Document Set.

Document Sets are a feature in SharePoint Server that enables an organization to manage a single deliverable, or work product, which can include multiple documents or files. A Document Set is a special kind of folder that combines unique Document Set attributes, the attributes and behavior of folders and documents, and provides a user interface (UI), metadata, and object model elements to help manage all aspects of the work product.

Metadata set to document set can be applied automatically for all the documents within that document set.

In your case you can create document set for each employee, set the metadata for that document set. And then all the documents uploaded in document set will have same meta data.

For more information refer:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/document-set-planning

https://en.share-gate.com/blog/document-sets-making-your-metadata-shine

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go. You can inherit the metadata of a document set to the documents added into the document set. You'd probably need to create Department-specific libraries with a document set for each employee. Then just set the employee name & ID to the document set's metadata and set it to be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Users can drag and drop files into the library, because required metadata is missing the files will be checked out.

Users can then use the Quick Edit view to quickly enter required metadata and check in the files.

Unless you use a scripted migration with calculated metadata values, or a 3rd party tool, you will not be able to make this much simpler for users without disabling the required metadata altogether.